# onkeydown doesn't work with javascript

Tags: javascript

why doesn't my function return an alert given this particular code?

```
function searchString() {
  if (event.keyCode == alert("Success!"); }
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" onkeydown="searchString();"/>
```

Comment: You need to specify `event` as the argument of your click handler

Comment: how do i do that? is that like `function searchString(event)`?

Comment: yup, exactly that :)

Comment: Your code is malformed. It seems like you have not even tried it yourself.

Comment: funny thing is this code worked on my computer but now doesn't work on another computer

Comment: @laine There are a few syntax errors involved. Please use something like www.jshint.com to help you debug the javascript code first.

Comment: @laine First of welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not be disheartened by all the negative points. All it means is that the question is not meeting the required standards. However, please continue to ask anything that you don't understand. There are many on this forum who will be willing to help you.

Comment: I am actually not disheartened I'm just kinda desperate right now because this code actually worked before and it's almost our defense :(

Comment: Take a look at my answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the `event` argument in your function. Otherwise `event` is undefined when you try to invoke the `keyCode` method:

```
function searchString(event) {
  if(event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Success!"); 
  }
}
```

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', searchString);

function searchString(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Success!"); 
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Press the <b>enter</b> key in the input below see your alert</p>

<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure javascript:

```
const search = document.getElementById('searchString');

search.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Note: 13 is the key code for the enter

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the actual `event` is being passed as an argument... otherwise, it will be unrecognised within the function. To see which code is tied to which key, please try the following.

```
function check(event)
{
    var keycode = event.keyCode;
    alert(keycode);
}
```

And then ...

`<input type="text" id="check" name="check" onkeydown="check();">`

The return key is tied with '13'. So if you just want to do something when it is pressed, do the following.

```
function searchString(event)
{
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("return key was pressed");
        // do something ....
    }
}
```

And the html code should be something like the following.

```
<input type="text" id="searchString" name="searchString" onkeydown="searchString();">
```

Please note that I have used '===' instead of '=='. It is now the recommended practise. Also, note that the forward slash at the end of `input` is not necessary.